# Cant get a form by name with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to apply some styles to a div that comes right after a form but, can't get it to work with jquery. I can't set an ID of CLASS to the form because is from a joomla module.

```
<form action="#" method="get" name="mod_Form"></form>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" style="font-size: 10px;">Some thing here...</a></div>
```

This is how I'm trying to do it with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[name=mod_Form]").next('div').css('color', 'green');
});
```

That code doesn't seem to work...

How can I accomplish my task?

Comment: Note that `$("form[name=mod_Form]")` is a bit more informative for people reading your code, and also likely more efficient.

Comment: I'd have quotation marks around the name: `$('[name="mod_Form"]')`.   [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). And check the selectors with the console (e.g. firebug) if it seems as if they aren't working.

Answer (score 2):

Link elements don't inherit the text color form their parent. You have to set it explicitly on them:

```
$("[name=mod_Form]").next('div').find('a').css('color', 'green');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/26nU9/)

If you want to set the color for the links and the content of the div, you can include the `div` with [`.andSelf` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/):

```
$("[name=mod_Form]").next('div').find('a').andSelf().css('color', 'green');
```

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing. Here's a demo showing the difference between link and non-link text inside the div: http://jsfiddle.net/KDMcW/

Answer (score 0):

Your code works.

http://jsfiddle.net/nHtTD/

In order to change the link's color Consider adding `find(a)`:

```
$("[name=mod_Form]").next('div').find("a").css('color', 'green');​​
```

EDIT: After reading your comments: (Works for me)

http://jsfiddle.net/nHtTD/1/

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to hide that div: $("[name=mod_Form]").next('div').addClass('hidden'); .hidden{ display:none; } and it isn't working either.